# Flutter hot reload doesn't work on autosave in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Flutter `hot reloads` every time VS Code `auto-saves` my project before. A few hours ago, I started experiencing this issue where `auto-saving` doesn't `hot-reload` my app. Pressing `Ctrl+S` manually triggers `hot reload` but `auto-saving` does not.  I've tried re-installing VS Code and Flutter SDK but the problem still exists.

My newly installed VS Code only has the following extensions and settings:

> Dart: v3.19.1
> Flutter: v3.19.0
> `Auto-save` is set to `afterDelay` of 1000ms

How do I hot reload when autosaving in vscode? Another person had the same issue two hours ago: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3110

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**An update in Dart & Flutter's VS Code extension is causing the issue.**

**===== Latest Version =====**

**3.42 and above**: You can enable hot reload on autosave in the latest version by setting Flutter Hot Reload On Save to `allIfDirty` in your VSCode settings.

**===== Old Versions =====**

**v3.41 and below:** You can enable hot reload on autosave in the latest version by setting `Flutter Hot Reload On Save` to `always` in your VSCode settings.

**v3.19:**  They disabled hot reload on autosave completely.

**v3.18 and below:**  The extension hot reloads automatically when auto saving.

Comment: I can't understand why you want auto-save to trigger a hot reload... that'd mess up your debugging!  (Not every change results in a valid syntax, or a hot-reloadable source text.)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Its more of preference. It makes development a lot easier since it only hot reloads when the compiler doesn't detect any errors in the code

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I agree with Uni. It's a nice feature I must say.  Just disable auto-save if you have to CTRL + S every time

Comment: @akifarhan They are going to have a setting in the next release. You can follow the github issue above for updates

Answer (score 4):

It's in the change notes for this release. It's an intended feature! (http://dartcode.org/releases/v3-19)

It says:

> #3033: Hot-reload-on-save no longer fires for Save events triggered by VS Code’s auto-save feature. Pressing Save manually will still trigger a reload even if there are no unsaved changes.

Comment: Why they did it? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
Just delete your VS cache folder and VS temp folder.
-> Press windows button and type:

%temp%

%appdata%

-> Check your launch.json in .vscode folder. delete and recreate if necessary.
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and it didn't work. The devs told me that it was caused by the latest version of dart and flutter extension.