# VS Code Flutter auto hot reload not working after updating

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile-development

After I updated my Dart extension in VS Code, it doesn't automatically hot-reload my Flutter codes even though I've turned on autosave. Does anyone have an idea about how to solve it?

Comment: i upgraded it to 3.19.1

Comment: have u found a solution

Answer (score 2):

If you using VS Code, Go to the **Settings > Extensions > Dart & Flutter**

Then select **always** in **Flutter Hot Reload On Save**

Congrats  Your problem is solved.

[PFA screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X772z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Run the `flutter doctor` command and make sure that flutter is installed properly on your machine.

Which channel are you running on? Make sure that you run on the stable channel, as long as it does not give you any compile time issues.

If the flutter doctor works, then make sure that, if you are running on iOS (Physical Device), that you have bonjour service enabled. This is required in order to make debugging work on physical devices (for iOS 14+). Please also make sure that you add **-v** command to the end of your deploy function, to increase the log verbosity.
Otherwise you can just deploy to the simulator.

If you are running on Android, there should not be any issues, unless there is a problem with the logcat. In this case you can try to go to android Studio and reboot the ADB (Android Debug Bridge), in which case the machine will try to reattach a debuggable process to your device. If it's still not working, then try another device. If that's not working, then add the **-v** command, I mentioned earlier, about log verbosity.

Post an update on your issue, once you have tried all of these suggestions.

[**EDIT**]
Please make sure that hot reload is enabled on the vscode settings.
Go to Settings > Search > Hot Reload, and make sure it's enabled for both Auto Save & Restart.

Please take a look at this image below:
[image]

**[EDIT ONCE AGAIN]**
If you look at the flutter documentation (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload) it says, that to run a flutter hot reload, you have to follow these steps:

> Run the app from a supported Flutter editor or a terminal window.
> Either a physical or virtual device can be the target. Only Flutter
> apps in debug mode can be hot reloaded. Modify one of the Dart files
> in your project. Most types of code changes can be hot reloaded; for a
> list of changes that require a hot restart, see Special cases. If
> you’re working in an IDE/editor that supports Flutter’s IDE tools,
> select Save All (cmd-s/ctrl-s), or click the hot reload button on the
> toolbar.

Make sure that you follow all the steps in the documentation, then let's talk on this post again (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload)

Comment: thank you, but I have tried all the suggestion, none of them worked for me, it still does not automatically hot reload my app

Comment: just updated my answer. Are your settings like mine?

Comment: yes, my settings are just that when I opened it

Comment: is there possibly something wrong with saving the files? but i already turned on autosave

Comment: but my project could hot reload in vscode before updating my dart extension, is there any problem with that?

Comment: can you try to rollback to the original version you were using? If you cloned the flutter repo, you can check your version history via git

Answer (score 1):

If you’re running the app at the command line using

```
flutter run
```

command, enter r in the terminal window to hot reload.

Try to run by clicking ****Run button**** worked in my case.

[**Like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdSxe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered over here: [Flutter doesn't hot reload on autosave in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975713/flutter-doesnt-hot-reload-on-autosave-in-vscode/65975714).  In short, *it is working as designed*.

Answer (score 0):

The "hot reload on save" feature was intended to run when the user specifically pressed save so they had some control over when it occurred. Some users experienced issues where autosave would cause it to fire when they didn't want it to, so this "bug" was recently fixed.

It turns out that for many users, hot-reload-on-autosave worked fine, so the next version of the Dart extension will include a setting to allow you to re-enable that.

```
"dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave": "always"
```

Answer (score 0):

For VS Code Go to 'File' -> 'Auto Save' make sure you have "check" Auto Save.